# how to Redis-cli command to mass insert CSV data into Redis persistence system?

Tags: awk, command-line, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

My CSV data looks something like this ->

```
    Header1   Header2
    Key100    Value100
    Key200    Value200
```

It has only two columns with Header as first row. The columns are keys and respective values.
Now, my requirement is -

1. I want to store key & value as String data type
2. Need to exclude the Header(the first row) while storing
3. Need to exclude null or " " keys
4. it is a ',' separated data
5. The word "Data:" should be appended to each key while inserting.

For example - for the above provided csv data, redis should store as -

```
Data:Key100
Data:Key200
```

### Result:

When I do `get Data:Key100` my output should be : `"Value100"`

Have tried with awk command but it is keep on giving error - invalid stream id specified

```
awk -F ',' 'FNR > 1 {print "XADD myStream \""($1=="" ? "NA" : $1)" column_1 "($2=="" ? "NA" : $2)" column_2 ... \n"}' data.csv | redis-cli --pipe
```

Please help me to get the command. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please post samples of input and expected output more clearly in your question, to make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question by adding the expected sample. Hope this clarifies. Thank you.

Comment: By using XADD, are you intentionally using a redis stream data type? A redis hash structure using HMSET would suit your data best.

Comment: Mass insertion (see https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert) gives speed benefits by using a raw redis protocol. You probably don’t know yet if you need high speed, so your question is a little confusing because it says you want to mass insert and you have used the —pipe parameter.

Comment: It might be best to work in the redis-cli interpreter to learn the commands and test your data structure before you automate the batch import with awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this, which sets an individual key to a value for each line of your file, but I am not sure why you seem to be trying to use a stream:

```
awk -F ',' 'FNR>1 { if(!$1){$1="NA"}; if(!$2){$2="NA"}; printf("SET %s %s\n",$1,$2)}'  data.csv | redis-cli --pipe
```

For this file (which has the key missing on line 3 and the value missing on line 5):

```
Header1,Header2
Key100,Value100
,fred
Key200,Value200
bill,
```

That produces this code:

```
SET Key100 Value100
SET NA fred
SET Key200 Value200
SET bill NA
```

Which then enables you to do this:

```
redis-cli get Key100
"Value100"
```

Also, you say you want to exclude null keys, but your code replaces them with `"NA"` and sets them anyway, so you may prefer to ignore them altogether with:

```
awk -F ',' 'FNR > 1 && $1 && $2 {printf("SET %s %s\n",$1,$2)}'  data.csv
```

which produces:

```
SET Key100 Value100
SET Key200 Value200
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the needful, but I forgot to add my another requirement. Can you please try to me help me on that part ? i.e., the provided word to be appended to all the keys while insert, for example -> my csv key is 1) Key100 then in redis it should store as Data:Key100 2) my csv key is Key200 then my redis should store as Data:Key200. Eventually, get Data:Key100 gives me the value.

Comment: just change the `printf` to `SET Data:%s %s\n`

Comment: On the same one, what if I dont  have my headers row and data start from first row?

Comment: Just remove `FNR > 1 &&` so that it looks like this `awk -F ','  '$1 && $2  {...}'`

Comment: `FNR>1` just tests if the record number in the file (i.e. the line number) is greater than 1, so it doesn't print the first line.

Comment: Mark Setchell - Can you please provide your assistance on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69754970/redis-mass-insertion-csv-data-is-not-inserting-to-redis