# Redis mass insertion CSV - data is not inserting to Redis

Tags: database, csv, awk, redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to insert the CSV data into Redis using the below command

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| long_ago/speech: | well-done speech |
| long-ago/debate: | well-done debate |
| long ago/work: | well-done work |

```
awk -F ',' 'FNR > 1 && $1 && $2 {printf("SET Topic:%s %s\n",$1,$2)}' data_topics.csv | redis-cli --pipe
```

The expectation is when I do

```
GET  "Topic:long_ago/speech:"
```

should print

```
>"well-done speech"
```

But I am not getting any output when I tried inserting 1000 rows in CSV. So have tried with the above 3 rows in CSV and getting the below error

```
[admin~]$ awk -F ',' 'FNR > 1 && $1 && $2 {printf("SET Topic:%s %s\n",$1,$2)}' data_topics.csv | redis-cli --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
ERR syntax error
ERR syntax error
ERR syntax error
Last reply received from the server.
errors: 3, Replies: 3
```

So I have tried adding double quotes in the 2nd column, now my CSV looks something like the below

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| long_ago/speech: | "well-done speech" |
| long-ago/debate: | "well-done debate" |
| long ago/work: | "well-done work" |

and this is the error I am getting now -

```
[admin~]$ awk -F ',' 'FNR > 1 && $1 && $2 {printf("SET Topic:%s %s\n",$1,$2)}' data_topics.csv | redis-cli --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
ERR Protocol error: unbalanced quotes in request
```

Please help me to insert my CSV data into Redis.

Comment: You probably need to sanitize your values (and maybe also your keys) before inserting in your database. As we do not know what your dataset is, it is difficult to say what type of sanitization is needed. It could be as simple as simple-quoting the values to handle spaces and double-quotes. And you probably don't need to modify your CSV. Your awk script can do it on the fly. But if you also have simple quotes in your values (e.g., `bob's hat`) this will not be enough. Same if your keys also need sanitization.

Comment: What you should probably do now is try to understand what's wrong with your dataset. Split your dataset in two halves and try to insert them. Repeat with the half that causes errors, until you find one single CSV row that cause errors. Look at it and try to understand the problem (spaces, quotes...) Adapt your awk script accordingly and test again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CSV called `data.csv` that contains this:

```
long_ago/speech:,well-done speech
long-ago/debate:,well-done debate
long-ago/work:,well-done work
```

You could use:

```
awk -F, '{printf("SET \"Topic:%s\" \"%s\"\n",$1,$2)}' data.csv | redis-cli --pipe
```

Then you could do:

```
redis-cli GET "Topic:long_ago/speech:"
"well-done speech"
```

Comment: This is giving response as  - 
$ awk -F, '{printf("SET \"Topic:%s\" \"%s\"\r\n",$1,$2)}' data.csv | redis-cli --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 4

> get "Topic:long_ago/speech:"
"well-done speech\r" .

"\r" is included at the end for each value

Comment: You can try removing `\r` from the `awk` script.

Comment: Sorry to say this but, have tried that and anyway it is printing `\r` in the value and my csv file data looks clean.

Comment: Ok, try using `cat -vet` to see carriage returns and line feeds like this `cat -vet DATA.CSV` and `awk -F, ... DATA.CSV | cat -vet` and `redis-cli GET "Topic:long_ago/speech:" | cat -vet` to see if you can work it out. Linefeeds show up as `$` and carriage returns as `^M`

Comment: Thank you, have tried it, `$cat -vet data.csv ` giving the response as `long_ago/speech:,well-done speech^M$`  How to fix this? Is it something to be removed from the file?

Comment: It's a nasty Windows thing. You can remove it with `tr -d '\r' < DATA.CSV > CLEANDATA.CSV`

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally, this worked for me after removing `\r` from the actual script. This is the final one -> `awk -F, '{printf("SET \"Topic:%s\" \"%s\"\n",$1,$2)}' CLEANDATA.CSV | redis-cli --pipe`. Thank you so much for your kindness once again.

Comment: Cool - glad we got there in the end. I have removed the spurious CR I had in my code too. Good luck with your project.